# httpd not starting with systemd on F17

Tags: apache-2.2, fedora, systemd

Title says it all. This is a fresh Fedora 17 system running on a Xen hypervisor. No idea why it won't start

```
[root@box~]  uname -a
Linux box.localhost 3.5.4-2.fc17.i686.PAE #1 SMP Wed Sep 26 22:10:23 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

[root@box~]  cat /etc/redhat-release
Fedora release 17 (Beefy Miracle)

[root@box~]  systemctl enable httpd.service
ln -s '/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service' '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/httpd.service'

[root@box~]  systemctl start httpd.service
Job failed. See system journal and 'systemctl status' for details.

[root@box~]  systemctl  status httpd.service
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server (prefork MPM)
          Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled)
          Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri, 19 Oct 2012 22:43:37 -0500; 3s ago
         Process: 18225 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k start (code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE)
          CGroup: name=systemd:/system/httpd.service

Oct 19 22:43:37 box.localhost systemd[18225]: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/sbin/httpd: No such file or directory

[root@box~]  ls -al /usr/sbin/httpd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 343496 Apr 30 04:56 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

Comment: What changes did you make to your `/tmp` directory?

Comment: /var/tmp is a symlink to /tmp and /tmp is mounted as:

tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent versions of Fedora/systemd include [a new feature](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ServicesPrivateTmp) which generates random private directories in `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` for individual system services.

This means that there are things you should check:

1. DO NOT symlink `/var/tmp` to `/tmp` or vice versa. These are treated separately and so you'll need to keep them separate.
2. Ensure that both `/var/tmp` and `/tmp` have 1777 permissions.

If this doesn't resolve the problem, you may have found a bug, and should [report it](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Fedora).

Comment: Wow that fixed it. Thanks! Weird how if I started it through /usr/sbin/httpd it would run fine, but not through systemd.

Comment: To add to that, also **do not** mount `/var/tmp` as tmpfs, as [its contents are normally expected to be preserved between reboots](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/2.2/fhs-5.15.html).

Comment: Also fixed a similar problem I had with `rtkit` on Debian Jessie.  The answer might apply to all systems using `systemd`?

Comment: @jopasserat Most likely. Fedora contributes _everything_ upstream, so that other distributions get it eventually.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! I fiddled around a bit with tmp symlinks and forgot about it later, a lot of services crashed without an error. I finally know why